# show keyboard for specific fragment in viewpager

Tags: java, android

I am implementing view pager with different fragments in it. I want to show show keyboard when a specific fragment opens. How can i do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a onPageChangeListener to your view pager and show the keyboard in onPageSelected for the given fragment

Comment: Great. Please consider accepting the answer ;) for internet points.